# Why do I keep getting this error 'RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in int_scalars'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to multiply all the row values and column values of a 2 dimensional numpy array with an explicit *for-loop*:

```
product_0 = 1
product_1 = 1
for x in arr:
   product_0 *= x[0]
   product_1 *= x[1]
```

I realize the product will blow up to become an extremely large number but from my previous experience python has had no memory problem dealing very very extremely large numbers. 
So from what I can tell this is a problem with numpy except I am not storing the gigantic product in a numpy array or any numpy data type for that matter its just a normal python variable.

Any idea how to fix this?

*Using non inplace multiplication hasn't helped `product_0 = x[0]*product_0`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `int` are represented in *arbitrary precision*, so they *cannot overflow*. But `numpy` uses C++ under the hood, so the highest long signed integer is with fixed precision, `2^63 - 1`. Your number is far beyond this value, having in average `((716-1)/2)^86507)`.

When you, in the `for` loop, extract the `x[0]` this is still a `numpy` object. To use the full power of python integers you need to clearly assign it as python `int`, like this:

```
product_0 = 1
product_1 = 1
for x in arr:
    t = int(x[0])
    product_0 = product_0 * t
```

and it **will not** overflow.

Following your comment, which makes your question more specific, your original problem is to calculate the **geometric mean** of the array for each row/column. Here the solution:

I generate first an array that has the same properties of your array:

```
arr = np.resize(np.random.randint(1,716,86507*2 ),(86507,2))
```

Then, calculate the geometric mean for each column/row:

```
from scipy import stats

gm_0 = stats.mstats.gmean(arr, axis = 0)
gm_1 = stats.mstats.gmean(arr, axis = 1)
```

`gm_0` will be an array that contains the geometric mean of the `x`and `y` coordinates. `gm_1` instead contains the geometric mean of the rows.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: The op wanted his array products to be separate , no need to join them

Comment: The text was saying "all the values"

Comment: using `np.shape()` my array has a shape of (86507,2).they are integer coordinates in (x,y) fashion and i am trying to get the geometric mean of all the x's and all the y's separately  none of the values inside the array should exceed 716 so the only number that should be big is the non numpy normal python variable called `product` .

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is compiled for 32 bit and not 64 bit , so while Python can handle this numpy will overflow for smaller values , if u want to use numpy then I recommend that you build it from source .

Edit
After some testing with

```
import numpy as np
x=np.abs(np.random.randn(1000,2)*1000)
np.max(x)
prod1=np.dtype('int32').type(1)
prod2=np.dtype('int32').type(1)
k=0
for i,j in x:
    prod1*=i
    prod2*=j
    k+=1
    print(k," ",prod1,prod2)

1.797693134e308 is the max value (to this many digits my numpy scalar was able to take)
```

if you run this you will see that numpy is able to handle quite a large value but when you said your max value is around 700 , even with a 1000 values my scalar overflowed.

As for how to fix this , rather than doing this manually the answer using scipy seems more viable now and is able to get the answer so i suggest that you go forward with that

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import gmean
x=np.abs(np.random.randn(1000,2)*1000)
print(gmean(x,axis=0))
```

Comment: but i am not even storing any big numbers in my numpy array the only big number in the program is the product except the product is just a normal python variable not a numpy datatype

Comment: can you try to find out after which value it starts to overflow ?

Comment: i put a `print(product_0)` statement in my for loop and as soon as it runs it gives the aforementioned error for the line `product_0 *= x[0]` and `product_1 *= x[1` after which it prints at first increasingly bigger numbers and then negative and then again positive numbers this cycle repeats for a while after which it prints a whole bunch of zeros. the last non zero number is `-2147483648` but the weird thing is there should be no negative numbers the array is actually the coordinates of all the non zero values obtained through `np.argwhere(arr1)` where arr1 is a seprate numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> So from what I can tell this is a problem with numpy except I am not storing the gigantic product in a numpy array or any numpy data type for that matter its just a normal python variable.

Your product may not be a NumPy array, but it *is* using a NumPy data type. `x[0]` and `x[1]` are NumPy scalars, and multiplying a Python int by a NumPy scalar produces a NumPy scalar. NumPy integers have a finite range.

While you technically could call `int` on `x[0]` and `x[1]` to get a Python int, it'd probably be better to avoid needing such huge ints. You say you're trying to perform this multiplication to compute a geometric mean; in that case, it'd be better to compute the geometric mean by transforming to and from logarithms, or to use [`scipy.stats.mstats.gmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.gmean.html), which uses logarithms under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with the following command in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

product_0 = np.prod(arr.astype(np.float64))
```

It can still reach np.inf if your numbers are large enough, but that can happen for any type.